# Is there a limit on the number of characters in a wallet.dat file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

I want to try to recover my wallet.dat file which has a small amount of Bitcoin, and I was wondering whether there was a character limit for passphrase encryption, or whether the app allows you to use an unlimited amount of characters for the wallet’s passphrase. I am using Bitcoin Core for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has never been a limitation on the characters or number of characters that could be used in the passphrase.

Comment: Does this include capital letters?

Comment: @OKprogrammer Yes. Even non-english (non-ascii) characters are allowed.